# How do I retrieve the SOFR (Secured Overnight Financing Rate) index/value in Mathematica?

Tags: finance, financialdata

SOFR doesn't show up in `FinancialData[]` (despite being a Bloomberg symbol). When I ask Wolfram|Alpha, it thinks I'm talking about "Overnight: The Movie". Am I holding it wrong, or is this really missing? Many loan arrangements are tied to it.

So far I've searched the output of `FinancialData[]`, tried to find an `Entity["Financial"]` for it, tried to get `Interpreter["FinancialIndex"]` to recognize it, and argued with the Alpha integration about it. What else should I try?

Cheers
-- perry

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Interest Rate data is readily available via `FinancialData` which, as a rule of thumb, tends to be more Equity and Currency focused.

From the documentation:

> "FinancialData can retrieve end-of-day data on US and other stocks and
> other financial instruments, as well as indices and currency exchange
> rates."

And the reason for the limited data:

> "FinancialData provides gateways to external financial data sources.
> Its use is subject to any restrictions associated with those sources,
> and **may require additional licensing**."

A quick check using `FinancialData[___ ~~ "SOFR" ~~ ___, "Lookup"]` returns `{}` and variations along `SOFR` such as `SR` (looking for futures or an index) etc. don't seem to throw anything up.

---

That said you can get SOFR from publicaly available sources online such as the [Federal Reserve Economic Data (FRED).](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SOFR)

If you want to download it programatically, you can sign up for [API key](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/docs/api/fred/) and then pull the data using `Import`.

---

If you have access to a Bloomberg terminal you could consider signing up for [Wolfram Finance Platform](https://www.wolfram.com/finance-platform/) that [allows you pull data from Bloomberg](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/service/BloombergTerminal.html)